# Can't include pifont

Tags: symbols

I'd like to insert "BALLOT X" symbol ✗ `U+2717`

I found `\ding{55}` command from `pifont` package, but when I try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pifont}

\begin{document}

%\XSolidBrush
\ding{55}
\end{document}
```

I get the following error:

```
! Font U/pzd/m/n/10=pzdr at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
! Font U/psy/m/n/10=psyr at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
```

This is my `pifont.sty`:

```
\ProvidesPackage{pifont}%
[2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a
Pi font support (SPQR)
]
\newcommand{\Pifont}[1]{\fontfamily{#1}\fontencoding{U}%
\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}\selectfont}
\newcommand{\Pisymbol}[2]{{\Pifont{#1}\char#2}}
\newcommand{\Pifill}[2]{\leavevmode
  \leaders\hbox{\makebox[0.2in]{\Pisymbol{#1}{#2}}}\hfill
  \kern\z@}
\newcommand{\Piline}[2]{\par\noindent\hspace{0.5in}\Pifill{#1}{#2}%
   \hspace{0.5in}\kern\z@\par}
\newenvironment{Pilist}[2]%
{\begin{list}{\Pisymbol{#1}{#2}}{}}%
{\end{list}}%
\def\Pinumber#1#2{\protect\Pisymbol{#1}{\arabic{#2}}}
\newenvironment{Piautolist}[2]{%
\ifnum \@enumdepth >3 \@toodeep\else
  \advance\@enumdepth \@ne
      \edef\@enumctr{enum\romannumeral\the\@enumdepth}%
  \expandafter\def\csname p@enum\romannumeral\the\@enumdepth\endcsname{}%
  \expandafter\def\csname labelenum\romannumeral\the\@enumdepth\endcsname{%
     \csname theenum\romannumeral\the\@enumdepth\endcsname}%
  \expandafter\def\csname theenum\romannumeral\the\@enumdepth\endcsname{%
     \Pinumber{#1}{enum\romannumeral\the\@enumdepth}}%
  \list{\csname label\@enumctr\endcsname}{%
        \@nmbrlisttrue
        \def\@listctr{\@enumctr}%
        \setcounter{\@enumctr}{#2}%
        \addtocounter{\@enumctr}{-1}%
        \def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}}
\fi
}{\endlist}
\newcommand{\ding}{\Pisymbol{pzd}}
\def\dingfill#1{\Pifill{pzd}{#1}}
\def\dingline#1{\Piline{pzd}{#1}}
\newenvironment{dinglist}[1]{\begin{Pilist}{pzd}{#1}}%
  {\end{Pilist}}
\newenvironment{dingautolist}[1]{\begin{Piautolist}{pzd}{#1}}%
  {\end{Piautolist}}
{\Pifont{pzd}} %ERROR
{\Pifont{psy}} %ERROR
\endinput
```

The problem is with the last 2 lines.

Can you fix it? Or suggest an other way to display this character?

Comment: Why do you think this error occurs from the last two lines? Your get the error `Metric (TFM) file not found` so you have to install the tfm file.

Comment: Your TeX distribution is broken or incomplete. Please, add what you're using.

Comment: @egreg `Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I needed to install `texlive-fonts-recommended` package:

`sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-recommended`

Thanks for Marco Daniel

Answer (score 11):

Maybe this also works:

```
tlmgr install zapfding
tlmgr install symbol
```

if you have TeX-Live manager `tlmgr` installed.
You don't have to install all fonts from `texlive-fonts-recommended`.

Comment: If this is just a suggestion rather than a tested solution, it should be a comment rather than an "Answer".

Comment: @AndrewSwann Solved it for me

Comment: I use texmaker on mac and second command worked for me.