# Error: ! Font \csname\endcsname=psyr at 10.95pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found

Tags: fonts, errors

I'm a LaTeX beginner and I tried to compile a LaTeX document without results.
The error displayed is:

> Couldn't find `ps.cfg'
>
> miktex-maketfm: No creation rule for font psyr.
>
> ! Font \csname\endcsname=psyr at 10.95pt not loadable: Metric (TFM)
>   file not fo und.  
>                      \endgroup \set@typeset@protect  l.116 \newpage
>                  ?

By reading this error I suppose that is related to a font (but I am not sure). 
Here is the list of package that I use:

```
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{epsfig} 
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{amsbsy} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{times} 
\usepackage{algorithmic} 
\usepackage{algorithm} 
\usepackage{openbib} 
\usepackage{cite} 
%\usepackage{flushend} 
\usepackage{enumerate} 
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage{psfrag,subfigure,fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{acronym} 
\usepackage{hhline} 
\usepackage{latexsym} 
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{url} 
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic} 
\usepackage{setspace} 
%\usepackage{threeparttable} 
\usepackage{xspace} 
\usepackage{supertabular} 
%\usepackage{glossary} 
\usepackage{eucal} 
\usepackage{stmaryrd} 
\usepackage{multicol} 
\usepackage{epstopdf} 
\usepackage{dsfont} 
\usepackage{bm,pmat,amsthm}
```

Is there anyone that could help me?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or hit Ctrl+K.

Comment: If you are using MiKTeX or TeX Live, is the TeX distribution package `symbol` installed?

Comment: Maybe you should remove some packages step by step, providing a MWE that help can be done more effiency....

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek thanks, this fixed the error for me (on macOS X, so no apt-get)

Answer (score 7):

Please try the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fonttable}

\begin{document}
\section{Symbol psyr}
\fonttable{psyr}
\end{document}
```

It should compile without error and results in a font table.  If it does not compile you have a problem like that @Heiko mentioned in his comment ...

[image: Fonttable Symbol]

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error, but after doing

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-recommended
```

it worked.

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59424/cant-include-pifont) may also be relevant.

Comment: On TexLive for macOS, the packages that are necessary to be installed and solve the error are `collection-fontsextra`, `collection-fontsrecommended`, and `collection-fontutils`. Installed with a macOS application: `TeX Live Utility`.

Answer (score 1):

Alternativelly, you can use `tlmgr gui` to install package `symbol` as Heiko Oberdiek pointed out.